# Are there any SuperCam spectra available?

Tags: mars, spectroscopy, spectra, planetary-science

A lot of pictures from the SuperCam, the NavCam or the Mastcam onboard the Perseverance rover are available online (for instance on the NASA and JPL websites). Have any SuperCam spectra been made public in a similar way?

Comment: @uhoh I wasn't quite sure where to put the question, since it's about the scientific data from a celestial body, not about the rover itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the spectra from SuperCam along with that from many other instruments is available from the NASA Planetary Data System (PDS) Geosciences Node. The overall landing page for all of the *Mars2020* instruments is [here](https://pds-geosciences.wustl.edu/missions/mars2020/) and the one specifically for SuperCam is [here](https://pds-geosciences.wustl.edu/missions/mars2020/supercam.htm).

Reading the documentation is highly recommended as PDS archive bundles such as this can be quite complicated, particularly for multi-function instrument such as SuperCam. PDS is designed for long-term storage of data from missions so the data format is extensively described and documented in XML format to explain what each byte, column, field etc of the data is and where it comes from. For the Mars2020 docs, there is:

- [Readme.txt](https://pds-geosciences.wustl.edu/m2020/urn-nasa-pds-mars2020_supercam/readme.txt) which gives a high-level overview of the SuperCam Bundle.
- The [SuperCam Bundle Software Interface Specification (SIS)](https://pds-geosciences.wustl.edu/m2020/urn-nasa-pds-mars2020_supercam/document/SuperCam_Bundle_SIS.pdf) which  describes the contents, format, and structure of the bundle, such as names and types (table, image etc) of datasets. The page says:  "Users who are unfamiliar with PDS archives should read this first."
- The [SuperCam PDS User Guide](https://pds-geosciences.wustl.edu/m2020/urn-nasa-pds-mars2020_supercam/document/SuperCam_PDS_Userguide.pdf) summarizes (it's still 81 pages...) information from other documents that is likely to be most useful to the science user and gives (most) of the gory details of how the data is collected and processed.

PDS make available a [Mars 2020 Analyst's Notebook](https://an.rsl.wustl.edu/help/Content/Perseverance%20Analyst%27s%20Notebook.htm) which could be handy for getting started with these data and there is the [PDS4 viewer](https://sbnwiki.astro.umd.edu/wiki/PDS4_Viewer) (PDS version 4 is the most recent and current version of the archive specification) which can read and display PDS4-labeled images and tables and is available for Windows, Mac and Linux.